# Partial order relation on subsets

Tags: co.combinatorics

I consider all $k$ element subsets of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and define a partial order relation $\prec$ as follows: $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}\prec\{b_1,\ldots,b_k\}$, if and only if $a_1<\cdots<a_k$, $b_1<\cdots<b_k$ and $a_i\leq b_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k$.

What is this partial order commonly called in the literature? Can someone point out references?

Thanks a lot,
Torsten

[edit] Here is a Hasse diagram of this partial order for $n=6$ and $k=3$:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/7pmk7

Comment: Essentially you are taking strictly increasing maps from {1,...,k} to {1,...,n}. Than, given two strictly increasing maps 
$f,g:\{1,...,k\}\to \{1,\dots,n\}$ you say that $f\prec g$ if $f(i)\leq g(i)$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$. I would call it just a pointwise order... I cannot help you with any reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This order is sometimes denoted $L(k,n-k)$ and has many interesting properties. See for instance Chapter 6 of http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/algcomb.pdf. For the characteristic polynomial of the Hasse diagram of $L(k,n-k)$ (considered as a graph), see Remark 5.6 of http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/vac.pdf.

Comment: The first link in the post no longer works - but it can still be found [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20111219145927/http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/algcomb.pdf). 
(Sorry for notifications from my several comments - I did not want to bump several old posts by editing, that's why I posted comments instead.)

Answer (score 7):

This is the [Bruhat order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_order) on $S_n / (S_k \times S_{n-k})$, which models the inclusion relations of Schubert varieties on the Grassmannian $Gr(k,n)$.  The elements of $S_n / (S_k \times S_{n-k})$ are generally modeled by their minimal length representatives, called Grassmann permutations.  You can biject your $k$-subset of $[n]$ to a Grassmann permutation by sending a $k$-subset $\lbrace a_1, \dots, a_k \rbrace$ (with $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_k$) to the permutation of $[n]$ whose window (one-line) notation is $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k b_1 b_2 \cdots b_{n-k}$ with $\lbrace b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{n-k} \rbrace$ denoting the complement of your given set, again ordered in increasing order $b_1 < b_2 < \cdots < b_{n-k}$.

Comment: it seems like you have to use \lbrace and \rbrace instead. (in comments, \{ and \} work.)

Comment: Thanks!  I've used \{ and \} successfully in the past, but it must have been in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

[I call this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00373-012-1281-9) the *compression order* on $[n]^{(r)}$, because it is the order induced by the operation of *left-compression* (or *left-shifting*) used in extremal set theory.